# How to access to a private variable used as by a property ( designTime package) from another unit (runtimepackage)

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

in order to create a component, I created a designtime and runtime packages, runtime package (lets call it RP140) contains the code of my component and requires rtl.dcp, designtime package (lets call it DclRP140) contains register procedure and requires DesignIDE, runtime package and rtl.dcp. Now I need to access private variables declared in the unit that belongs to "DclRP140" package, from another unit that belongs to "RP140",  I created a simple code which contains the relevant part, just to make it easier to understand:

```
unit MyComponentRegister;

interface

uses Classes, MyComponent;

type
  TEvent = procedure(sender: TObject) of object;

  TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
  private
    FMyproperty: String;
    FMyEvent: TEvent;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  published
    property myProperty: String read FMyproperty write FMyproperty
      default initial_value;
    property myEvent: TEvent read FMyEvent write FMyEvent;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [TMyComponent]);
end;

Constructor TMyComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FMyproperty := initial_value;
end;

end.
```

the other unit contains the main code of my component:

```
unit myComponent;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Classes;

type
  TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
  public
    procedure myProcedure(avalue: string);
  end;

implementation

procedure TMyComponent.myProcedure(avalue: string);
begin
  FMyproperty := avalue; // I want to access to FMyproperty
  if assigned(Fmyevent) then // I want to access to fMyEvent
    // do some work
end;

end.
```

So first, I have to tell you that I'm new to creating packages and components, so am I doing it the right way? or is there something wrong?

Second,as I said before, what I want to do is to access to private variables declared in 'MyComponentRegister' from 'myComponent', I tried many tricks but none of them worked, for sure there is a way to do that, but I cant find it with my limited experience.So, how I can I solve this one??

Comment: I reformatted your code. Please can you make sure your code is readable when you next post a question. I removed all the spurious comments. There's absolutely no point in having a comment that tells you that `public` means that the following members are public. Or one that tells you that `private` means the following members are private. Don't use comments that echo what is self-evident.

Comment: You just not splitting design- and run-time packages. Class should go into run-time, anything IDE related (`RegisterComponent` in the minimal case) should go into design-time package which, in turn, `requires` corresponding run-time package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to define your component in multiple places. That's not possible. Your code declares two distinct classes. That's one more than you need.

Do it like so:

```
unit MyComponent;

interface

uses
  Classes;

type
  TEvent = procedure(sender: TObject) of object;

  TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
  private
    FMyproperty: String;
    FMyEvent: TEvent;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    procedure myProcedure(avalue: string);
  published
    property myProperty: String read FMyproperty write FMyproperty;
    property myEvent: TEvent read FMyEvent write FMyEvent;
  end;

implementation

constructor TMyComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyComponent.myProcedure(avalue: string);
begin
  FMyproperty := avalue;
  if assigned(FMyEvent) then
    ; // do some work
end;

end.
```

This unit is included in both design time and run time packages.

```
unit MyComponentRegister;

interface

uses
  Classes, MyComponent;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [TMyComponent]);
end;

end.
```

This second unit is included only in your design time package. Note that it does not defined the component because that is defined in the `MyComponent` which is uses.